# jwd filter does not work laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel

hello everyone :) in my laravel 5 file routes.php, and return this error

"BadMethodCallException compiled.php line in 6243:
Method filter does not exist."

but I worked correctly laravel 4.2

My code is:

```
Route::filter('authMobile', function($route, $request)
{   
try{
   $token = JWTAuth::getToken();
   $user = JWTAuth::toUser($token);
   $tokenStr = JWTAuth::getToken()->__toString();
   if ($user->token != $tokenStr){
    throw new Exception("Login Token don't match");
   }
   Session::put('user',$user->id);
}catch(Exception $e){
    return Response::json(array(
        'error' => true,
        'message' => 'Invalid Session: '.$e->getMessage()
    ));
}
});
```

Thanks, regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in the error:

> "BadMethodCallException compiled.php line in 6243: Method filter does not exist."

This is about this part: `Route::filter`.

In Laravel 5 [Middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/master/middleware) is the preferred way to handle it, instead of filters. They are not entirely gone:

> Filters are not removed in Laravel 5. You can still bind and use your own custom filters using `before` and `after`.

[*source Upgrade Guide 4.2 > 5.0*](https://laravel.com/docs/master/upgrade#upgrade-5.0) (Scroll to
*Route Filters*) Here is explained how you can keep it working with `Route`,  but I would suggest migration anyway;

> The following Laravel features have been deprecated and will be removed entirely with the release of Laravel 5.2 in December 2015:
>
> - Route filters have been deprecated in preference of middleware.

[*source Upgrade Guide 5.1.0*](https://laravel.com/docs/master/upgrade#upgrade-5.1.0) (Scroll to *Deprecations*)

You can turn your `authMobile` into middleware by following the steps as posted in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/master/middleware), but I would suggest you update your package from composer too and take a look at the [jwt-auth Authentication docs](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/wiki/Authentication), which has detailed [information](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/wiki/Authentication#middleware-and-filters) on how to make  it work in Laravel 5 with the already included middleware.

If you are using `0.5.*` of `jwt-auth` you just enable them in your `<appname>/Http/Kernel.php`:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    ...
    'jwt.auth'      => \Tymon\JWTAuth\Middleware\GetUserFromToken::class,
    'jwt.refresh'   => \Tymon\JWTAuth\Middleware\RefreshToken::class,        
];
```

Then you can include it in [Controller](https://laravel.com/docs/master/controllers#controller-middleware) level for example:

```
public function __construct()
{
    // Here we can say we want to jwt auth all resource functions except index and show.
    $this->middleware('jwt.auth', ['except' => ['index','show']]);
}
```

Or in your routes.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['before' => 'jwt.auth', 'after' => 'jwt.refresh']], function () {
..etc
```

Instead of applying the filters like you would in Laravel 4.2